# Unable to start SQL Server Instance 2008 R2 - DB file corrupt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database, database-administration

I was not able to start the SQL Server 2008 R2 production DB instance. After reading the log file error message is

**" The log scan number passed to log scan in database ‘master’ is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication."**

After reading several post i realize that my MASTER DB file is corrupted. I have followed the below setup

1. Copy the Master.mdf and Masterlog.ldf file from Template location to My Database Data folder.

   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Templates  to D:\MSSQL\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

Note: Same error occur when i copy the all DB file like Master, MasterLog, MSDBData, MSDBlog, Model and ModelLog

2. When i run my MSSQLSEVER instance different problem occur.

In My server i had only C, D- Drive i dont have the E drive. How can i override these below error path.

**Error LOG**

> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State:
>   1.
>
> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open
>   file 
>   e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf
>   for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified.).
>
> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State:
>   101.
>
> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      Unable to open the physical file
>
> "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf".
>   Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified.)".
>
> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State:
>   1.
>
> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating
>   system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred
>   while creating or opening file
>   'e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf'.
>   Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the
>   operation.
>
> 2012-10-24 02:51:12.79 spid5s      File activation failure. The
>   physical file name
>   "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf"
>   may be incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You have problems, Microsoft provides: [Rebuild System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx).

Comment: Is it not nice how easy it is to find a standard solution when one is capable of using google or looking up things in the documentation ;)